# How can I use a FlexMock hash matcher to verify part of an array value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to verify that my Rails code calls ActiveRecord's all method (all is syntactic sugar for find :all) like this:

```
      records = Record.all
        :limit => RECORD_LIMIT, :offset => record_offset,
        :select => 'id',
        :conditions => [ 'record_type = ? AND content_score >= ?', 'user', min_content_score ],
        :order => 'content_score DESC'
```

The only part of this code that I care about in this instance is the :conditions param, and I only care about the SQL snippet, not the actual values of the bound variables. I can use a FlexMock hash matcher to assert that (at least) the :conditions param is present like so:

```
mock.should_receive(:all).with FlexMock.hsh :conditions => []
```

However, that only matches calls where the value of the :conditions param is the empty array. What I really want is something like this:

```
mock.should_receive(:all).with FlexMock.hsh [ 'record_type = ? AND content_score >= ?', Object, Object ]
```

But tragically, as irb reveals, 'user' and Object are not equivalent:

```
>> '' === Object
```

Any good ideas? Are nested matchers possible?

Comment: Ugh... the source code seems to indicate that what I want to do is not possible:

http://flexmock.rubyforge.org/classes/FlexMock/HashMatcher.html#M000106

Unless I can override the right == method... stay tuned.

Comment: If only the FlexMock::HashMatcher#=== method was defined as "@hash.all? { |k, v| v == target[k] }", my monkey-patching of == would work. Maybe it is time to cast Open Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duck-punching this shouldn't be necessary.  You can define your own argument matcher quite easily:

```
class HashKeyMatcher
  def initialize( key )
    @key = key
  end

  def ===( other )
    other.respond_to?( :keys ) && other.keys.include? @key
  end

  def inspect() "HashKeyMatcher( #{@key.inspect} )"; end
end
```

Then you use it like so:

```
mock.should_receive(:all).
  with( HashKeyMatcher.new( :conditions ) ).
  and_return []
```

Place the HashKeyMatcher somewhere that you can access from your tests.

If you like, you can make it available in a manner similar to the other Flexmock argument matchers by opening the Flexmock class and adding a new method:

```
class Flexmock
  def self.key( hash_key )
    HashKeyMatcher.new hash_key
  end
end
```

Then you can write your test like this:

```
mock.should_receive( :all ).
  with( Flexmock.key( :conditions ) ).
  and_return []
```

Comment: OK, I like this better then my insane solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this requires both monkey-patching FlexMock and an object, so it is not for the faint-of-heart. :)

First, monkey-patch FlexMock::HashMatcher to call == on the expectation object, not the actual object:

```
class FlexMock::HashMatcher
  def ===(target)
    @hash.all? { |k, v| v == target[k] }
  end
end
```

Next, construct an object and redefine its == method:

```
conditions_matcher = Object.new
conditions_matcher.instance_eval do
  def ==(other)
    other.first == 'record_type = ? AND content_score >= ?'
  end
end
```

Finally, set up your FlexMock expectations:

```
mock.should_receive(:all).
    with(FlexMock.hsh(:conditions => conditions_matcher)).
    and_return []
```

This works for all of the following calls:

```
Record.all :conditions => [ 'record_type = ? AND content_score >= ?' ]
Record.all :conditions => [ 'record_type = ? AND content_score >= ?', 'foo' ]
Record.all :conditions => [ 'record_type = ? AND content_score >= ?', 'foo', 5.0 ]
```

Ruby is insane, but in a good way. :)